Save Emacs buffer state to recover subsequently not saving to file
I made a program that jump the cursor at the beginning of the word that starts with a specific letter.
Example, there is a buffer what contains next sentence, for simplicity only a sentence. The buffer doesn't contains modifications, it is the same as its correspondent file and the content @---- appears in mode line.
I am not sure at all. Maybe you will help me. I will see it soon.
User desires to jump at the start of the word "sure", run the program and press s. Every word that starts with s letter gets in front of its body letters A, B, C .., that are marked as overlays with different font with capital letters.
It will appear:
I am not Asure at all. Maybe you will help me. I will Bsee it Csoon.
User types letter "a" and the cursor jumps at the start of the word "sure" and the letters A B C and their overlays are deleted. Finally the cursor is at the start of the word sure:
I am not |sure at all. Maybe you will help me. I will see it soon.
If are many words that starts with a specific letter in current window, words that exceeds the number of alphabetic letters, then it will appears the system with two letters AA, AB, AC, .. ZZ, that user types to jump the cursor everywhere in his current window. Maybe the awkward combinations will be eliminated.
The problem with Emacs is: after cursor moving, the buffer content is the same with the initial content, but it appear modified at mode line with @**-- detail. How can I do to run the program but to not affect the state of unmodified buffer, to appear @---- in mode line.

Does C-h f with-silent-modifications solve your problem?

It works, the buffer status is preserved, thank you very much.

This question is similar to: How to perform a modifying action without modifying buffer?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The behavior you describe sounds very similar to the package avy, which is actively maintained and in all the repos. Take a look at it and see if it's a good match for your requirement.

You can wrap (with-silent-modifications ...) around code which 'modifies' the buffer in some way, but doesn't actually change the buffer text.
with-silent-modifications is a Lisp macro in `subr.el'.

(with-silent-modifications &rest BODY)

Execute BODY, pretending it does not modify the buffer.
This macro is typically used around modifications of
text properties that do not really affect the buffer's content.
If BODY performs real modifications to the buffer's text, other
than cosmetic ones, undo data may become corrupted.

This macro will run BODY normally, but doesn't count its buffer
modifications as being buffer modifications.  This affects things
like `buffer-modified-p', checking whether the file is locked by
someone else, running buffer modification hooks, and other things
of that nature.


I saw it, if there is something wrong the undo doesn't work, you must kill the buffer and reopen again after file. That inconvenient is bigger than to see wrong @**-- or @---- tag in mode line. I will give up it, maybe there is something better!

You would only use with-silent-modifications with "cosmetic" changes to the buffer.  My impression was you were only modifying overlays?  If you're changing the buffer's actual text content, you wouldn't use this macro.
